# Como criar um processo filho a um processo existente no windows - C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Preciso chamar via **CreateProcess()** ou outra função do windows um processo e vincular a um processo já existente, é possível?

obrigado!

Comment: Especifique melhor o que está querendo, tente por um exemplo.

Comment: Um programa x está executando no windows, quero via outro programa, identificar esse processo (essa parte já fiz) e criar um outro processo (chamar outro programa) vinculado como sub-processo ao programa que eu identifiquei anteriormente. No linux usa-se o comando Fork() para atribuir um subprocesso a um processo já rodando. Gostaria de fazer algo semelhante no windows.

Comment: O que consegui foi criar um sub-processo do programa que estou executando, mas nao consegui criar um subprocesso de um outro programa (processo).

Comment: Como se faz isso no Linux?  Que eu saiba, `fork()` só cria processos filhos do processo que o invoca, nunca de um terceiro processo. Como é que um terceiro processo, que não sabe que ganhou um filho, seria capaz de coletá-lo quando terminar (via `waitpid()` e aliados)?

Comment: é verdade @Wtrmute o fork() cria somente filho dele mesmo. Mas minha indagação é justamente essa, é possivel criar um processo e vincular a um terceiro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente, não. A `CreateProcess()` (bem como a `fork()` em Unix) criam processos ligados ao processo que os criou (por exemplo, é a ele que eles reportam *status* de saída, é dele que eles herdam as variáveis de ambiente, *etc.*). Um terceiro processo não saberia que teve um filho criado por outrem para receber o *status* de saída ou coisa que o valha.

Se você precisa criar um processo que se comunique com outro, já existente, o Windows tem várias opções de [Comunicação Interprocessual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) (IPC, na sigla em inglês) que você pode tentar usar. Mas o processo preexistente tem que dar suporte a esses métodos de comunicação.

Em ultimíssimo caso, [`DebugActiveProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) e aliados (principalmente [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) podem te permitir (sob certas circunstâncias) a injetar informação num processo ativo, mas o modo de determinar o mapeamento de variáveis para endereços de memória é extremamente não-trivial. Adicionar código, então, para fazer com que o processo depurado execute `CreateProcess()` ele próprio e gere o processo físico exige um conhecimento de linguagem de máquina bastante profundo, e pode no final das contas não atender o seu *verdadeiro* requisito, seja ele qual for.